# Second monitor powering off in dual monitor setup

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

I have two identical monitors, one with DVI and the other with HDMI. When idle, the main screen goes to sleep, but the second screen powers off due to no signal. This means I have to hit the power button to resume my second screen instead of moving the mouse around.

Does anybody know why this happens, or how to fix it? My guess is the hardware in the monitor doesn't realize it's connected after the computer goes to sleep.

Comment: If you swap the connections, run the current HDMI one as DVI and vice versa does the issue persist?

Comment: No, why is this?

Comment: More than anything else to verify this is not a problem with one monitor.  The Dell monitors and computers we use do no do what you describe with HDMI, I don't believe this is in the HDMI spec either. So you may have a faulty something, or a monitor designed oddly...